# Adding two convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is finite and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ is also finite, why is it that you can add the two series term by term and get the sum of the two series?  Surely this is reordering the series.

Answer (score 12):

The $N$:th partial sum 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N (a_n+b_n) = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n + \sum_{n=1}^N b_n.
$$
Hence, as $N \to \infty$,
\begin{align}
\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N (a_n+b_n) &= \lim_{N\to\infty} \left(\sum_{n=1}^N a_n + \sum_{n=1}^N b_n \right) \\
&= \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n + \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N b_n
\end{align}
since both limits exist by assumption.

Answer (score 7):

If $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converge,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty } (x_n+y_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty }x_n+\lim_{n\to\infty }y_n.$$

Set $x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ and $y_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^n b_k$ and you'll get your result.